# Spark persistent table is not available in the other node

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple Spark(2.3.0) Standalone cluster with 1 master and 2 workers (node-1 and node-2). I saved my dataframe as a persistent table into Hive metastore using the saveAsTable command with pyspark on node-1:

```
>>> df.write.saveAsTable("test")
```

It works fine. I can restart pyspark on that node (node-1) and can see that the table is still there:

```
>>> spark.sql('show tables').show()
+--------+---------+-----------+
|database|tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+---------+-----------+
| default|     test|      false|
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

But when I go to the other node (node-2), I get the following:

```
>>> spark.sql('show tables').show()
+--------+---------+-----------+
|database|tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+---------+-----------+
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Can anyone help me on how we can use the table in node-2?

Comment: This also gives the same results:`df.write.option("path", " hdfs://node-1:9000/test").format("parquet").saveAsTable("test")`

Comment: Did you consider using `createGlobalTempView`?

Comment: I do not consider it, because I want to have a persistent table even after I close the application, in this case I use pyspark as the application..

Answer (score 0):

This is because metastore data is save locally in an Apache Derby database. I solve this by using mysql instead of derby.